# 80番ポートで起動させているnginxのWebサーバーに外部からアクセスできない

Tags: macos, nginx

nginxを80番ポートで起動させて以下のように設定しているのですが、どういうわけか外部からアクセスすることができません。

外部アクセスは[cman.jp](http://www.cman.jp/network/support/port.html)で検証しています。

ルータのポート開放はできています。
<s>`lsof -i :80`を打っても、nginxが出てきません。</s>sudoで実行すると出てきました。

- 環境

  - Mac OS X Yosemite(10.10)
  - nginx v1.6.2(homebrewでインストール)

**`sudo lsof -i :80`**

```
nginx   39791   root    6u  IPv4 0x940c44dd2ca1aa21      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   39792 nobody    6u  IPv4 0x940c44dd2ca1aa21      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   39793 nobody    6u  IPv4 0x940c44dd2ca1aa21      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   39794 nobody    6u  IPv4 0x940c44dd2ca1aa21      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   39795 nobody    6u  IPv4 0x940c44dd2ca1aa21      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {
    listen       *:80;
    server_name  hoge.example.asia;

    location / {
      root   /Users/seioo/Devs/Web/;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      autoindex on;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 念の為に確認しますが、`lsof -i :80` は root 権限で実行していますか？

Comment: `sudo lsof -i :80`と実行したら、nginxが出てきました!
てっきりsudoなしで全部見えるものだと思っていました。
ありがとうございます!

Comment: 了解です。そうなりますと、nginx を起動しているホストのフィルタリング設定の問題かもしれません。`sudo ipfw list` の実行結果を追記していただけますか？

Comment: ipfwがありません.. Yosemiteだからでしょうか

Comment: ちなみにMacのFirewallではnginxの通信(incoming connections)を許可しています

Comment: 了解です、それでは firewall の問題ではないですね。何か分かりましたらまたコメントします。

Comment: 外部ネットワーク(cman.jp)からのポート確認とのことですが、経路上にルータ等は存在していないのでしょうか？またISPによっては80番ポートを閉じている可能性もあります。

Comment: 経路上にルータは存在していますが、ポート開放はできています。
ApacheやPumaでWebサーバーを立てたときには外部からTCP80番ポートでアクセスできたので、ISPが邪魔しているということもないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

[superuser（英語）に似たような質問がありました](https://superuser.com/questions/519289/mac-firewall-blocking-nginx-port-80-from-external-side)。

シンボリックリンクだとファイアウォールがunblockできないのが理由のような気がします。
設定から手動か、以下のコマンドで実態を足せば治ると思います

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add `readlink \`which nginx\``
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblockapp `readlink \`which nginx\``
```

バージョン上げるたびに治さないといけないのがちょっと面倒ですが…